# unable to import play.http.httpErrorHandler in java playframework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt

i have a class named ErrorHandler which implements HttpErrorHandler interface in play 2.5.x framework.HttpErrorHandler interface comes from import  play.http.httpErrorHandler but in my case there is no jar for this import. i googled it to find jar or command to write in build.sbt but failed to find any solution.

Comment: shouldn't this be `play.http.HttpErrorHandler`?

Comment: indeed it is.sorry it was a typo here.